# ARM template webhook on storage acount keeps failing AzurePipeline

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Having issues getting an ARM template to run successfully for a webhook sitting on a blob storage. The hook already exists on the storage, but for obvious reasons, we want the creation of it in the pipeline job. The issue I am getting is the following relevant error:

`##[error]InvalidRequest: There is an existing tracked system topic for the given source /subscriptions/xxxxx-fa00-4048-9d12-4b3ce3d40d34/resourceGroups/dev-companyName/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageAccountName. Only one system topic is allowed per source.`

When I check the subscription on storageAccountName, the subscription topic appears as :
storageAccountName-xxxxx-802d-4436-bb67-f8d4a60fb5bd.

This error is telling me the resource is attempting to create but erring out because the hook is already present? Confused.

My Template pretty much follows exactly what is listed on MS : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/blob-event-quickstart-template

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName').name]",
      "location": "East US",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "kind": "BlobStorage",
      "properties": {
        "accessTier": "Hot"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics",
      "apiVersion": "2021-12-01",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName').name]",
      "location": "eastus",
      "properties": {
        "source": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',variables('storageAccountName').name)]",
        "topicType": "Microsoft.Storage.StorageAccounts"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',variables('storageAccountName').name)]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2021-12-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics/eventSubscriptions",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}',variables('storageAccountName').name, variables('subscriptions').eventSubscriptions.dataStorageBlobCreatedHookZipfile)]",
      "properties": {
        "destination": {
          "endpointType": "WebHook",
          "properties": {
            "endpointUrl": "[variables('functionUrls').zipFileProcessorUrl]"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "subjectBeginsWith": "",
          "subjectEndsWith": "",
          "isSubjectCaseSensitive": false,
          "includedEventTypes": [
            "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
          ]
        }      
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "resourceId('Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics',variables('storageAccountName').name)]"
      ]
    }
```

iirc ARM templates should always attempt to create but not destroy. Wondering what I might be doing incorrectly.